# variadic function pointer points to a function with preused arguments

Tags: c, function-pointers, variadic-functions

let's assume this variadic function is printing nice logs (without knowing its implementation because we don't care)

```
int printLog(int bla, int foo, const char *format, ...);
```

in the following code how do I affect the arguments?

```
void myFunction(int param)
{
    typedef int (*myPrint) (const char *, ...);
    if(param > 0)
    {
         myPrint = printLog; //how do I pass half of the argument here?
    }
    else
    {
         myPrint = printLog(1,2,...); //this is what I would like
    }

   //then use it
   myPrint("Hello World");
   unsigned int blah=1;
   myPrint("blah is %d",blah);
}
```

Comment: Simple answer is: You can't. If there is a `va_list` variant of `printLog` then you could create a proper `myPrint` function that passes the correct arguments to `printLog`. Otherwise you might possibly solve it by using vararg function-like macros.

Comment: This is called currying.